# Firestore not retrieving all documents from a collection

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a collection like this:

```
Rooms(collection)
    -C1(document)
    -D1(document) 
    -E1(document)
    -F1(document)
```

I want to get all the documents here, and put them in a list.

My code so far(RoomList is a private global variable that I initialize in the onCreate):

```
private void getRooms (){

    CollectionReference rooms = db.collection("Rooms");
    rooms.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                    Room r = new Room();
                    r.setRoomNumber(document.getId());
                    Map<String, Object> data = document.getData();
                    r.setDescription(data.get("Description").toString());
                    RoomList.add(r);
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Every time I run the debugger, it completely skips over the onComplete method, and doesn't change the RoomList.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RoomList` is always empty because `onComplete()` method is called asynchronous which means that is called even before you are trying to add those objects of `Room` class to the list. To solve this, you need to move the declaration of your list inside the `onComplete` method like this:

```
private void getRooms (){
    CollectionReference rooms = db.collection("Rooms");
    rooms.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            List<Room> list = new ArrayList<>();
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                    Room r = new Room();
                    r.setRoomNumber(document.getId());
                    Map<String, Object> data = document.getData();
                    r.setDescription(data.get("Description").toString());
                    RoomList.add(r);
                }
            }
            Log("TAG", list);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't work for me. I'm using a recycler view, should I put this in the activity or the adapter?

Comment: No, I rebuilt it using data binding.

Comment: Did my answer helped you in any way?

Comment: No, same issue, still don't know why